# IE 11 is not showing "Show Content" popup message

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, ssl, internet-explorer-11

I am getting below error when trying to open another https site (with self signed certificate) in iframe and IE11.

"Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate. For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in Internet Explorer Help."

When using IE9 or IE8, we used to get the same error along with a pop-up message "Show Content" clicking on which will display the content. But IE 11 is not displaying "Show Content" option.

Can you please help in enabling that option for IE11? I researched in SO and lot of other places. The option given was to install the certificate. Is there a way to enable "Show Content" option without going through certificate installation path?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable it manually: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-content-advisor-internet-explorer-10-11

Comment: I followed all the steps, but still I could not see "Show Content" popup message. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try opening and closing the browser first.